# Apk from expo issue

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk, npx

I've developed my app using expo with react-native and type script, for the entirety of my development I used `npx expo start` to run and test my application. I am currently trying to bundle it to an APK with `eas build -p android --profile preview` (according to expo documentation). The APK I am getting doesn't work; it crashes every time I try to start it after installation.
My eas.json

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I tried using `adb logcat` to understand the logs but haven't found anything valuable:

```
/data/data/com.*.myapp/lib-main
07-30 19:58:25.249 28613 29609 D SoLoader: libexpo-modules-core.so found on /data/app/~~auisghsPKDGuFzpW4b0C0Q==/com.*.myapp-AgdjN0bcWCy6xfENs1Iezw==/lib/arm64
07-30 19:58:25.249 28613 29609 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libexpo-modules-core.so
07-30 19:58:25.250 28613 29598 I AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016ee190, ME: 0x00000000
07-30 19:58:25.253 28613 29609 V SoLoader: libturbomodulejsijni.so not found on /data/data/com.*.myapp/lib-main
07-30 19:58:25.253 28613 29609 D SoLoader: libturbomodulejsijni.so found on /data/app/~~auisghsPKDGuFzpW4b0C0Q==/com.*.myapp-AgdjN0bcWCy6xfENs1Iezw==/lib/arm64
07-30 19:58:25.253 28613 29609 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libturbomodulejsijni.so
07-30 19:58:25.255 28613 29609 I ExpoModulesCore: ✅ JSI interop was installed
07-30 19:58:25.256  1104  5549 E surfaceflinger: [frame_perf] perfboost open boost file failed
07-30 19:58:25.257  1104  1888 E surfaceflinger: [frame_perf] perfboost open boost file failed
07-30 19:58:25.258 28613 29609 I ExpoModulesCore: ✅ Constants were exported
07-30 19:58:25.262   602   602 I hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry android.hardware.graphics.mapper@4.0::IMapper/default in either framework or device manifest.
07-30 19:58:25.262 28613 29598 I Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
07-30 19:58:25.262   602   602 I hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry android.hardware.graphics.mapper@3.0::IMapper/default in either framework or device manifest.
07-30 19:58:25.262 28613 29598 W Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
07-30 19:58:25.273  1104  1480 E surfaceflinger: [frame_perf] AutoTurboBoostQuery fd<0 failed, errno=Inappropriate ioctl for device
07-30 19:58:25.273  1104  1480 E surfaceflinger: [frame_perf] AutoBoostConfigQuery fd<0 failed, errno=No such file or directory
07-30 19:58:25.279  1561  1847 D ArtManagerInternalImpl: /data/misc/iorapd/com.*.myapp/1/com.*.myapp.MainActivity/compiled_traces/compiled_trace.pb doesn't exist
07-30 19:58:25.281  1561  1874 I ===> HoustonPackage: addLaunchTimeInfo: for com.*.myapp/.MainActivity isCold:true launchTime:285
07-30 19:58:25.281  1561  1874 I 322     : com.*.myapp#30#285
07-30 19:58:25.281  1561  1847 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.*.myapp/.MainActivity: +285ms
```

I tried running my apk after bundling it with expo and it crashed without any error codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I've had a similar problem with stack navigation

Since then I always run `npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler` then `npx expo install @react-native-masked-view/masked-view` then `npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`. I also `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` at the top of my App.tsx or App.js.
Keep in mind this instructions may be a little excessive. I don't know exactly what step fixed the issue. But I have not run into it ever since.